# Convert point from coordinate system (0,800) to coordinate system (50,-50) jFrame<->opengl

Tags: java, math, opengl, awt, coordinates

I have a point in the following coordinate system:

Java AWT:

```
0,0|------------------------|
   |                        |
   |  (middle p. 400,300)   |
   |                        |
   |------------------------|800,600
```

and I want to convert it to the following system:

OpenGL

```
  50,50|------------------------|
       |                        |
       |     (middle p. 0,0)    |
       |                        |
       |------------------------|-50,-50
```

Any idea how can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, what you want to do is convert from a (rectangular) coordinate system `A` to coordinate system `B`.

First map the source coordinate system, `A` to a normalized range `[0, 1]`:

```
double nx = x / (x1 - x0);
double ny = y / (y1 - y0);
```

Where `(x0, y0)` is the top left corner and `(x1, y1)` is the bottom right corner. Then map it to the new coordinate system:

```
double px = X0 + nx * (X1 - X0);
double py = Y0 + ny * (Y1 - Y0);
```

Where `(X0, Y0)` is the top left corner of your new coordinate system and `(X1, Y1)` is the bottom right corner of the new coordinate system.

This will work for any two rectangular coordinate systems.

Comment: Thanks I've tried your formula and works very well!! Too bad I can't give points yet...

Comment: This should work for 3d rectangle right? I don't see any reason why it should not work for a 3rd dimension by calculating the same nz and pz. Am I missing any point?

Comment: @Wizard: Assuming the dimensions are Cartesian coordinates, sure. This would work in n-dimensions as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
public Point awtToOpenGL(Point p) {
  Point newP = new Point();
  newP.setX(50 - (p.getX() / 8));
  newP.setY(50 - (p.getY() / 6));
  return newP;
}
```

[EDIT] Got the origo wrong. New try.

Since the openGL system is 100 wide and the AWT is 800 wide we need to divide the x value by 8. By the same logic y needs to be divided by 6. Since both x and y start at 50 and go down all we need to do then is to subtract the value from 50.

Comment: Hello, Thank you very much for your help, but seems its not working totally right where I should be getting (50,50) I'm getting (50,-50). More precisely at top left vertex in opengl.

Comment: Yes, I got the starting coordinates wrong. This should work though.

Comment: Thanks that made it! Could you explain better how it works? Where does the number 8 and 6 come from? From 800x600? Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome! I added an explanation, I hope that made it clearer.